# How to let Jenkins build the correct .war file?

Tags: maven, tomcat, jenkins, war

I am building a Webapplication for a Tomcat Server with the help of Maven and Jenkins.

The Problem ist, that the Structure of the .war file after unpacking by Tomcat is not in a way that it works, neither in a "tomcat conform" way (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html).

How can i fix this?

- Change the structure of my source code?
- Change the .pom so that maven builds it correctly?
- I have to change the outcome of the .war after unpacking by myself so that it works?

Details:
This is a project I took over, not one i build by myself.
[image: This is the source code structure]

[image: This is the Jenkins unpacked .war file structure]

[image: This is the structure how it is needed on the server. (tomcat standard conform, as i see it)]

Comment: I don't understand why someone would down-vote a perfectly valid question, upon which many people who start with webapps are stumbling? And without any explanation. Therefore upvoted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow the [maven conventions for folder layout](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) which means `src/main/java` for source like Java files. Within `src/main/webapp/`  things which belong more to web apps only..Like `web.xml`, jsp files etc. Furthermore you need to set the correct `<packaging>..</packaging>` in your pom file which is `war` in your case.

```
 |-- pom.xml
 `-- src
     `-- main
         |-- java
         |   `-- com
         |       `-- example
         |           `-- projects
         |               `-- SampleAction.java
         |-- resources
         |   `-- images
         |       `-- sampleimage.jpg
         `-- webapp
             |-- WEB-INF
             |   `-- web.xml
             |-- index.jsp
             `-- jsp
                 `-- websource.jsp
```

Apart from that i would recommend that you first create your war file on command line and don't use Jenkins in the first steps otherwise you more sources of errors in your project. If the war file will be created correctly and can be deployed to Tomcat manually without any problem you can go a step further and use a CI solution like Jenkins.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It is hard to get good answers on basic questions in the internet. seems everybody is a pro.